# How to write a test that checks API rate limiting is working?

Tags: javascript, testing, acceptance-testing

I have a function that makes an external API call. This API has a limit of 6 requests a second so I've setup a simple rate limiter using https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter.

My question is: how can I go about writing a test that asserts that this API call only gets called 6 times a second or less?

We are currently using nock to intercept and mock API calls in our test suite if that makes a difference :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock

Thank you!